# Order by date, while grouping matches by another column

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by

I have this query

```
SELECT *, COUNT(app.id) AS totalApps FROM users JOIN app ON app.id = users.id
  GROUP BY app.id ORDER BY app.time DESC LIMIT ?
```

which is supposed to get all results from "users" ordered by another column (time) in a related table (the id from the app tables references the id from the users table).

The issue I have is that the grouping is done before the ordering by date, so I get very old results. But I need the grouping in order to get distinct users, because each user can have multiple 'apps'... Is there a different way to achieve this?

---

Table users:

```
id TEXT PRIMARY KEY
```

Table app:

```
id TEXT
time DATETIME
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

in my SELECT query I want to get a list of users, ordered by the app.time column. But because one user can have multiple app records associated, I could get duplicate users, that's why I used GROUP BY. But then the order is messed up

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  .. you actual result and your expected  result

Comment: is `app.id = users.id` correct? Typically the id of the app table would be it's unique identifier rather than a reference to the user of the app. I'd suggest editing your question and providing the schema/create sql for the tables and some example data and the results that you expect.

Comment: yes, it references the id from the users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is that the SELECT is an aggregate query as it contains a GROUP BY clause :-

> There are two types of simple SELECT statement - aggregate and
> non-aggregate queries. A simple SELECT statement is an aggregate query
> if it contains either a GROUP BY clause or one or more aggregate
> functions in the result-set.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

And thus that the column's value for that group, will be an arbitrary value the column of that group (first according to scan/search, I suspect, hence the lower values) :-

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY
> clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated
> once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the
> result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the
> dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each
> non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then
> each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting
> entirely of NULL values.

So in short you cannot rely upon the column values that aren't part of the group/aggregation, when it's an aggregate query.

Therefore have have to retrieve the required values using an aggregate expression, such as max(app.time). However, you can't ORDER by this value (not sure exactly why by it's probably inherrent in the efficiency aspect)

### HOWEVER

What you can do is use the query to build a CTE and then sort without aggregates involved.

Consider the following, which I think mimics your problem:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS app;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT);
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d');

CREATE TABLE app (the_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id INTEGER, appname TEXT, time TEXT);
INSERT INTO app (id,appname,time) VALUES
    (4,'app9',721),(4,'app10',7654),(4,'app11',11),
        (3,'app1',1000),(3,'app2',7),
        (2,'app3',10),(2,'app4',101),(2,'app5',1),
        (1,'app6',15),(1,'app7',7),(1,'app8',212),
        (4,'app9',721),(4,'app10',7654),(4,'app11',11),
        (3,'app1',1000),(3,'app2',7),
        (2,'app3',10),(2,'app4',101),(2,'app5',1),
        (1,'app6',15),(1,'app7',7),(1,'app8',212)
    ;
    SELECT * FROM users;
    SELECT * FROM app;
    
    SELECT username 
      ,count(app.id) 
      , max(app.time) AS latest_time
        , min(app.time) AS earliest_time
    FROM users JOIN app ON users.id = app.id 
    GROUP BY users.id
    ORDER BY max(app.time)
    ;
```

This results in :-

[image]

Where although the latest time for each group has been extracted the final result hasn't been sorted as you would think.

Wrapping it into a CTE can fix that  e.g. :-

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT username 
        ,count(app.id) 
        , max(app.time) AS latest_time
        , min(app.time) AS earliest_time
    FROM users JOIN app ON users.id = app.id 
    GROUP BY users.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte1 ORDER BY cast(latest_time AS INTEGER) DESC;
```

and now :-

[image]

- Note simple integers have been used instead of real times for my convenience.

Comment: After trying your code I was getting the same bad results, so I checked deeper in my code and I found out that the problem was that I had sample data in the future and in the browser it was not displayed correctly :(  Sorry about wasting all of your time... Anyways, it seems that both the cte and the version with just ORDER by max(app.time)  produces the same results so I guess that at least in my case sqlite orders them by the aggregate expression ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the newest date in every group, you could just `MAX` them:

```
SELECT
  *,
  COUNT(app.id) AS totalApps,
  MAX(app.time) AS latestDate
FROM users
  JOIN app ON app.id = users.id
GROUP BY app.id
ORDER BY latestDate DESC
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: sorry, it doest work. I was not converting the dates correctly in the browser lol

Answer (score 1):

You could use windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(app.id) OVER(PARTITION BY app.id) AS totalApps 
FROM users 
JOIN app 
  ON app.id = users.id
ORDER BY app.time DESC
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: @Alex Windowed function are supported starting from 3.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: the problem is not selection but ordering

Comment: But maybe he could avoid grouping then, and then the ordering would work

Answer (score 0):

Try to grouping by id and time and then order by time.

```
select ... 
group by app.id desc, app.time
```

I assume that id is unique in app table.
and how you assign ID to? maybe you have enough to  *order by id desc*